# Cross-browser speech recognition?

Tags: javascript, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I'm trying to build a web search engine with Speech Recognition support, just like google.

So far, it works on Chrome but not on Firefox. I read from Mozilla's site that it doesn't properly support web speech API but how for instance google search and youtube works also on Firefox? Is there any 3rd party API/library for cross-browser support?

I enabled the following settings on firefox but still does not work.

### about:config

```
media.webspeech.recognition.enable       => true
media.webspeech.recognition.force_enable => true
```

Here is what I've done and works on Chrome but not on Firefox. Am I doing it wrong?

```
var recognition = null;

if (window.hasOwnProperty('webkitSpeechRecognition') || window.hasOwnProperty('SpeechRecognition'))
    recognition = new webkitSpeechRecognition() || new SpeechRecognition();

if (recognition) {
    recognition.continuous = false;
    recognition.interimResults = false;
    recognition.lang = 'en-US';
    // recognition.maxAlternatives = 1;
    recognition.start();

    recognition.onresult = function (e) {
        document.getElementById('search').value = e.results[0][0].transcript;
        recognition.stop();
    };
    
    recognition.onerror = function (e) {
        console.log('failed!');
        recognition.stop();
    };
} else {
    alert('Your web browser does not support SpeechRecognition. Try Chrome.');
}
```

Comment: `how for instance google search and youtube works` - It uses a google-powered API.  The "Note" [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechRecognition) indicates that's also what Chrome does.

Comment: Thanks James for the answer. Is there any workaround for now?

Comment: Pay to use google api?  https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/pricing